# Koltin Code is not syntax-highlighted : Only happens in .kt file

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Week ago, it used to be working fine. I think it's cause by I changed the gradle path in system like this [link](https://www.360logica.com/blog/how-to-configure-gradle-on-windows-machine/). It only happens on .kt, others like build.gradle are fairly highlighted. 
[image]

Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codemobiles.project_eva"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = "8"
        sourceCompatibility = "8"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Already editted the post.

Comment: File->invalidate caches/restart

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Solution : I completely wipe out the android studio to fix this [problem](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-completely-uninstall-Android-Studio)